# Custom single product page not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce, I changed single-product.php and placed an "if" statement inside the loop to load a custom page for a specific product.

```
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

if (is_product_category( 'Benefit')) {
    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-benefit' );
}else{
    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
}
        endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

My problem is the content-single-product-benefit.php called by the first part of the "if" is ALWAYS loaded (for all products).
I suspect a very stupid php syntax error but I spent an hour on this and can't see it. Both php pages called work fine on their own. Somehow I can't get that "if" right. What am I doing wrong??
Thx for your help ^^

Comment: Can you use this code inside the `while()` loop to output the categories the product belongs to? And then try on a non-benefit product, and let us know the output? `$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ); var_dump( $terms );`

Comment: Thanks for answering. The code outputs `array(1) { [6]=> object(stdClass)#102 (11) { ["term_id"]=> int(6) ["name"]=> string(8) "benefit" ["slug"]=> string(8) "benefit" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(6) ["taxonomy"]=> string(11) "product_cat" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(1) ["object_id"]=> int(11) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } }` on the benefit product page...

Comment: ...and `array(1) { [7]=> object(stdClass)#102 (11) { ["term_id"]=> int(7) ["name"]=> string(9) "books" ["slug"]=> string(9) "books" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(7) ["taxonomy"]=> string(11) "product_cat" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(1) ["object_id"]=> int(8) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } }` on another page I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[is_product_category()](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_product_category.html) function only works if archive page is being displayed, same as the Wordpress [is_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) function. Since you use this function inside the `single-product.php` file, and that is template for a singular page, above functions will not work. Try with:

```
has_term( 'Benefit', 'product_cat', $post );
```

Comment: Thank you Danijel!! I overlooked that. 'has_term()' works perfectly.